# Dojo widget creation within a context node

Tags: dojo

So, I know I can query for nodes not just in the entire DOM but also within a context node, like this:

```
var myNode = dojo.query('#formId', 'idContext');
```

This way I can get the right node even if there is another using the same id in the DOM.

What I'm trying is to create widgets based on a contextualized node. Instead of :

```
    new Form({
        method: 'post',
        action: 'aaa/bbb'
    }, 'formId');
```

I'm trying

```
    new Form({
        method: 'post',
        action: 'aaa/bbb'
    }, myNode);
```

But FBug logs the error:

```
TypeError: _13.hasChildNodes is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

while(_13.hasChildNodes()){
```

So, it seems I'm setting a wrong object in Form's second parameter... The usage explained in dojo docs says:

```
Usage:
var foo = new dijit.form.Form(/* Object? */ params, /* **DomNode**|String */ srcNodeRef);
```

I feel I'm misunderstanding something here... Wut do you think?

Thanks...

Comment: Note that [id attributes should be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute) within a document in legal HTML markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are passing a dojo `NodeList` object as the second parameter to the Form constructor.  The dojo.query method returns a [NodeList](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/NodeList.html#dojo-nodelist), not a single dom element.  The second (optional) parameter to a Widget constructor is a single dom node, not a Node List.

The following works

```
require(['dojo/dom','dijit/form/Form'],function(dom,Form){
    new Form({
        method: 'post',
        action: 'aaa/bbb'
    }, dom.byId('formId'));
});
```

It probably goes without saying that having multiple elements with the same ID on a page​ is a bad practice, but it you absolutely need to do  that, you can do something like `dojo.query('#testNode','idContext')[0]` to get the first node with the id `testNode` rooted at the node with the id `idContext`.

```
require(['dojo/query','dijit/form/Form'],function(query,Form){
    new Form({
        method: 'post',
        action: 'aaa/bbb'
    }, query('#formId','idContext')[0]);
});
```

Comment: Oh! man, I was trying query('#formId','idContext').at(0), but I got the same error. Is at(0) returning a NodeList also?. Is this due to the dojo/query chaining strategy?

Comment: You are correct.  the .at method also returns a NodeList http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojo/NodeList#at.  Seems like jquery has spoiled everyone with making the jquery objects much more forgiving than dojo.